# How do I name a theme file for view?

Tags: views, 8, theming

I am trying to theme a block from my view.  I have a view called slides and it is creating a block.  I have a template file I want this block to use.  I have looked at the documentation for themes and the pattern to follow is

```
views-block--<viewname>.html.twig
```

or

```
block--views-block--<viewname>-displayid.html.twig
```

I can't find displayid for my block so I am trying to get that first option to work, but No matter what I do my block wont seem to take on the template I have written.

my template is named

```
views-block--slideshow.html.twig
```

What am I doing wrong with my names?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
block--views-block--slideshow-block-1.html.twig
```

This is what it supposed to be.  When configuring the block it gives the entire file name and I just needed .html.twig on the end of what the block name is in the configuration page for the block.

Comment: somehow when I copied and pasted I missed the `block--` part.

Answer (score 1):

In your development.services.yaml file set twig debug to true and disable the cache by setting value to false.

After that you will see theme suggestions by inspecting element in browser.

Comment: If you can't find the file, just let me know, I will help you.

Answer (score 0):

In Drupal 7 under ADVANCED you just need to click the theme information link and it will show you all the template names.

[image]

In Drupal 8, you're are expected to turn on twig debug and see the template file suggestions. See [Locating Template Files with Debugging](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/theming/twig/locating-template-files-with-debugging)

Comment: I cant find anything like this in d8

Comment: In your edit view, Did you click on ADVANCED? (located on the far right)

Comment: Yeah the last thing on the list is CSS Class

Comment: Dang, I guess Drupal 8 is different.

Comment: https://www.drupal.org/node/2354645

yeah according to this the naming convention should just allow it to override the template

Answer (score 0):

To quote [drupal.org](https://www.drupal.org/node/2354645)

> Also one more example with Views, if you have a block created by views with a view name "front_news" and display id "block_1" then the theme hook suggestion would be: block--views-block--front-news-block-1.html.twig (notice, when you have underscores in a display id or in a view name - you have to transform them in to a single dash)

Well in drupal 7 the "display id" is the **machine name** under "other"

[image]

Lets pretend the above picture is your Slides view.

Assuming its the same for 8, then it would be block--views-block--slides-block.html.twig (for the above picture)

If your machine name is block_1 then it's block--views-block--slides-block-1.html.twig